# How to concatenate certain strings to every element of array

Tags: perl

I have a file WordNetTest3.txt which has some  words separated by a white space  and are elements of array called @unique_words . I want to concatenate TXD,RXD,CTS and RTS at the end of first element and these should become the four elements of  a separate array . Then again I want to concatenate TXD,RXD,CTS and RTS at the end of second element and these should become the four elements of second array and so on with all elements of @unique_words .I'v written a code for one element but for all elements i am not able to iterate.

```
my $a='TXD';
my $b='RXD';
my $c='CTS';
my $d='RTS';


my $filenam = 'WordNetTest3.txt' ;
open my $f , '<' , $filenam or die "Cannot read '$filenam': $!\n" ;



for ( @unique_words ) {
$array0[0] =$unique_words[0].$a;
$array0[1] =$unique_words[0].$b;
$array0[2] =$unique_words[0].$c;
$array0[3] =$unique_words[0].$d;
}

open $f , '>' , $filenam or die "Cannot read '$filenam': $!\n" ;

foreach (@array0) {
print $f "$_\n";
}

#print $f "@array0\n" ;
close $f ;
```

Comment: It's not really clear what result you want. Please add an extract of input file and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you `open` your file, you need to read from it. Perl doesn't know that you expect the filename to 'make it's way' into `@unique_words`.

You can read your file line by line by using:

```
while ( my $line = <$f> ) {

}
```

Likewise - even if you had declared `@array0` properly, you'll be overwriting it each time, which won't do you much good.

Also: Turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. They're practically mandatory when posting code to Stack Overflow.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @suffixes = qw ( TXD RXD CTS RTS );

my $filenam = 'WordNetTest3.txt';
open my $input,  '<', $filenam       or die "Cannot read '$filenam': $!\n";
open my $output, '>', "$filenam.NEW" or die $!;

while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
    chomp($line);
    for my $suffix (@suffixes) {
        print {$output} $line . $suffix, "\n";
    }
}

close($input);
close($output);
```

(This is assuming it's one word per line in our file)